# Python Pandas - Convert String-Class to Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime

I need to filter some data. I need to get some rows between 2 dates from a Pandas-DataSet.

The variables are defined as:

```
start = datetime.strptime(diaginput[5],"%d.%m.%Y")
end = datetime.strptime(diaginput[6],"%d.%m.%Y")
# output: 2015-01-01 00:00:00 
# type (start): <class 'datetime.datetime'>
# type (end): <class 'datetime.datetime'>

consumption['date'] = pd.to_datetime(consumption['date'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
# output line 99: 2016-09-01 02:45:00,
# type (consumption['date']): <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

The problem occures when executing the code for filtering data:

```
consumption[(consumption['date'] > start ) & (consumption['date'] <= end )]
# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Question: How can I properly filter the data between both dates?

Comment: Please get a dtype for `consumption['date']`, and put it here to make sure that the change format to `datetime` has been done correctly.
`consumption['date'].dtype`

Answer (score 0):

I have **solved** it:

```
# Filter data between two dates 
consumption = consumption.loc[(consumption['date'] >= start) 
                 & (consumption['date'] < end )]
```